Multilinear non-commutative Khintchine inequality
Let $g_1,\ldots,g_k$ be independent standard Gaussians and for each index $(i_1,\ldots,i_k)\in [n]^k$ let $A_{i_1,\ldots,i_k}$ be a $d\times d$ symmetric matrix.
Question: Is there a known bound for the quantity
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\left\|\sum_{i_1,\ldots,i_k=1}^ng_{i_1}\cdots g_{i_k}A_{i_1,\ldots,i_k}\right\|_\textrm{op},
\end{align}
in terms of the $A_i$?
Note that when $k=1$, i.e.,
\begin{align}
X=\sum_{i=1}^kg_iA_i,
\end{align}
the non-commutative Khintchine inequality states that
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\|X\|\lesssim \sqrt{\log d}\left\|\sum_{i=1}^kA_i^2\right\|^\frac{1}{2}.
\end{align}
One might hope to use this iteratively with some sort of decoupling inequality to obtain a bound in terms of $\sum_i A_i^2$, but I have not been able to locate such an argument in the literature.
